# Access is denied in BackgroundTaskBuilder.Register

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro

```
var builder=new BackgroundTaskBuilder();

builder.Name=name;
builder.TaskEntryPoint=taskEntryPoint;
builder.SetTrigger(trigger);

if(condition!=null)
  builder.AddCondition(condition);

builder.Register(); // in this step I get exception System.UnauthorizedAccessException. Additional information: Access is denied.
```

This exception is throwed in Windows 8 release preview.
In consumer preview I did not get this exception.

I use SystemTrigger (SystemtriggerType.UserPresent) and SystemCondition(SystemConditionType.InternetAvailable)

In Package.appxmanifest file I set System event checkbox to true and input Entry point value.
Also in Package.appxmanifest code I removed 'Executable' attribute.

Maybe someone know how I can fix it?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: But when I set SystemTrigger (SystemTriggerType.InternetAvailable) and SystemCondition(SystemConditionType.UserPresent), then it is working.

Answer (score 5):

Some SystemTriggers,however do need the app to be on the lock screen:
SessionConnected ,UserPresent,UserAway and ControlChannelReset If you use these triggers without beging on the lock screen ,the BackgroundTaskBuilder.Register() call will fail with "acess denied"

Comment: Also in the Microsoft documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.background.systemtriggertype